# Excel Macro checkbox cannot checked or unchecked

Tags: excel, vba

I enabled all the macro security settings in excel trusted center , also tried excel 2007 and 2013. I cannot check or uncheck the checkbox in one of my notebooks.
I copy the excel to another notebook , it's working. Does anybody know what I can do in my first notebook in order to make the macro work?

Comment: Is there any code in the _open-event of the workbook or any of the sheets?